# jqplot error: Uncaught Canvas dimension not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a simple graph made from an array that looks like this:

```
var plot2 = [[1,1.3,"1.3"],[2,0.3,"0.3"],[3,3.3,"3.3"],[4,1.7,"1.7"]];
```

and then it's added to a div like this.

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('graph', [plot2],{
  grid:{
    background:"transparent",
    borderColor:"#6c9922",
    gridLineColor:"#6c9922",
    shadow:false
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      tickOptions:{formatString:'%.0f'},
      pad: 0,
      min:0,
      max:5
    },
    yaxis: {
      tickOptions:{formatString:'%.1f'},
      pad: 0,
      min:0,
      max:5
    },
  },
  series:[{
    lineWidth:2,
    markerOptions: {size:2,style:"circle"}
  }],
  seriesDefaults:{
    showMarker:true,
    pointLabels:{ show:true }
  },
  seriesColors:["#ffffff"]
});
```

My problem is that some users of my website is reporting that they can't see the graph, both using latest Chrome and Firefox, and that they get and error saying

```
Uncaught Canvas dimension not set jquery.jqplot.min.js:57
```

Some of them say that the graph only works if they have zoom-level set to 100%.

None of this makes much sense to since and everything works perfect on every system I've tried.

So does anybody have any idea what can be wrong?

I've searched for the error but the only place I can find it is in the source code of the jqplot plugin.

Comment: Which version of JQPlot and JQuery are you using? Do you experiment this error too? Can you share the web link with us?

Comment: I got it working, somehow. Really not sure what I did and what happened, but users er reporting it working again after a few changes to the script. It's a protected page, so I can't give you a link, and I didn't get the error on any computer I tried.

Comment: But thanks for your reply;o)

Comment: I realized the thing about the axes' min/max after the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to the attributes array, which seemed to work. It must have had something to do with the min and/or max values on the axes, though I don't know for sure, since I never got any error.

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('graph', [plot2],{
  grid:{
    background:"transparent",
    borderColor:"#6c9922",
    gridLineColor:"#6c9922",
    shadow:false
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      tickOptions:{formatString:'%.0f'},
      pad: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
      tickOptions:{formatString:'%.1f'},
      pad: 0
    },
  },
  series:[{
    lineWidth:2,
    markerOptions: {size:2,style:"circle"}
  }],
  seriesDefaults:{
    showMarker:true,
    pointLabels:{ show:true }
  },
  seriesColors:["#ffffff"]
});
```